# Optimal BoneCP configuration

Tags: connection-pooling, bonecp

I my web application ,BoneCP DB connection pool configuration as following, it is creating too may DB connection

1. I need to know what is the default number of DB connection below configuration created
2. What is the optimal BoneCP configuration( avoiding unwanted connection)

```html
<bean id="appDataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource" destroy-method="close">
            <property name="driverClass" value="${database.driverClassName}" />
            <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${database.url}" />
            <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
            <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
            <!--<property name="idleConnectionTestPeriodInMinutes" value="2"/>-->
            <property name="maxConnectionsPerPartition" value="15"/>
            <property name="minConnectionsPerPartition" value="1"/>
            <property name="partitionCount" value="4"/>
            <property name="acquireIncrement" value="2"/>
            <property name="statementsCacheSize" value="100"/>
            <property name="releaseHelperThreads" value="5"/>
        </bean>
```

Comment: According to [docs](https://jolbox.com/configuration.html) you will have up to `15*4=60` max and `4*1` min connections. Looks like `releaseHelperThreads` should not be greater than `partitionCount`.

Comment: Thanks  Luis Muñoz